# unrar'ing everything in subdirectories without getting into a loop

Tags: linux, shell, for, rar

So I've been trying to unrar multiple `.rar` files in lots of different folders. Some are packed a little differently and looping is causing a problem.

```
- folder 1
        - file.part01.rar
        - file.part02.rar
        - ...
- folder 2
        - file.r01
        - file.r02
        - file.rar
- folder 3
        - file1.rar
        - file2.rar
        - ...
```

after doing `for f in *.rar; do unrar e $f;done` or something similar, it gets into a loop and keeps unrar'ing files it's already done. This is because `part01.rar` & `part02.rar` both are rar files and satisfies the command.

Is there anything I could do to stop this loop?

I have over 50 folders so don't want to go through all of them individually.

Comment: Why don't you create a list of files and then send that to rar... find |xargs comes to  mind, instead of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to exclude the files that end in `partN.rar` where `N` is greater than 1. With `zsh`:

```
set -o extendedglob
for file (./**/(^*part<2->).rar(N.)) echo unrar e $file
```

Remove `echo` when satisfied with what it's going to do.

With `bash`, it's a bit more complicated:

```
(export LC_ALL=C; shopt -s extglob globstar nullglob
for file in ./**/!(*part*(0)@([2-9]|[1-9]+([0-9]))).rar; do
  [ -f "$file" ] || continue
  [ -L "$file" ] && continue
  echo unrar e "$file"
done)
```

Or with GNU `find`:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '*.rar' -type f -regextype egrep \
  ! -regex '.*part0*([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)\.rar' \
  -exec echo unrar e {} \;
```

(that one also considers hidden rar files or rar files in hidden directories).

Or you could try and parse the output of `unrar l` on the files to determine which are single-volume archives or the first volume of a multi-volume archive.

Here tested with unrar 5.61 from [rarlab.com](https://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm) on version 5 RAR archives (and assuming there's no archive named like `$'whatever\nDetails: whatever.rar'`), with `zsh`:

```
is_first_volume() {
  unrar l "${1-$REPLY}" 2>&1 | awk '
    /^Details: / {
       is_rar = /RAR/
       if (/volume/) volume = $NF
       exit
    }
    END {
      if (!is_rar || volume > 1) exit 1
    }'
}

for file (./**/*.rar(N.+is_first_volume)) echo unrar e $file
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
find . -type f -name '*.rar' -print0 | xargs -0I{} unrar e {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to take a snapshot of the `.rar` files, unrar these only *and don't unrar any further `.rar` files that are inside the original stapshot of rar files*.

```
# put all files currently in the directory in a variable
csc_rarfiles=(*.rar)
# now iterate over the files contained in the array and unrar only those
for f in "${csc_rarfiles[*]}"; do unrar e "$f"; done
```

Comment: Please comment if the above is not what you're looking for and edit your question to make it clearer *if that's the case*...  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

```
unrar e -r -o- *.rar
```

Works like a charm.  That's to extract to the current directory, you could also add a target directory to extract all the files to there.

http://www.beginninglinux.com/home/data-compression/unrar-all-files-from-multiple-subdirectories-at-once